# Dropdown menu problems, DIV and or CSS issues

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, slideshow, submenu

Alright, I've periodically looked and messed around with this for around 6 weeks and so far have been unable to figure out how to solve this thing. Though I assume it's something small and relatively simple to people with more experience.

*Background*:
I am starting with a template that had a good js slideshow that I liked and started customizing it. When i got to a certain point I realized I wanted to add a drop-down menu. When I first added the `ul` sub-menu for the drop-down nothing appeared to happen. After messing with it for some time i created a test page where I only added the drop-down menu to see if the js was effecting it in any way and it worked as expected. I then added only the js in to see if my 0 knowledge of js was effecting it and it worked (no alignment info).

At this point i went back to the original code and it stopped working. so I went online and got some example code to put in that I knew worked and that too didn't work. At one point I started messing with the `div` tags in the html and was able to get some resemblance of what I was looking for though the content started shifting down sometimes on rollover; other times it would drop the content 100% of the time. I moved to playing with `z-index`'s and no matter what I did that didn't seem to make a difference either.

*The question*:
What the heck am I not seeing here? All I'm looking for is a drop-down that goes over top of the js slideshow without pushing it down. I'm pretty sure this issue revolves around the fact that there are so many `div`'s to make this layout and they're conflicting somehow. Any help someone could give would be absolutely amazing because I'm going crazy.

Here is the index page with issues:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Mitchell Faherty</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tms-0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tms_presets.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page1">
<!--==============================header=================================-->
<header>
  <div class="main">
    <h1> <a href="index.html">Mitchell Faherty</a> <em>Wedding photo / Videos</em> </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-row">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container_12">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="grid_12">
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <!-- 
                <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About1</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About2</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About3</a></li>
                </ul>
                -->
                <li><a href="photo-gallery.html">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="items">
          <li> <img src="images/front-slider/slider-img1.jpg" alt=""> </li>
          <li> <img src="images/front-slider/slider-img2.jpg" alt=""> </li>
          <li> <img src="images/front-slider/slider-img3.jpg" alt=""> </li>
      <li> <img src="images/front-slider/slider-img4.jpg" alt=""> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!--==============================footer=================================-->
<footer>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container_12">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="grid_3 suffix_3">
          <ul class="list-services">
            <li><a class="item-1" href=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="item-2" href=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="item-3" href=""></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.slider')._TMS({
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutQuint',
        preset: 'slideDown',
        slideshow: 7000,
        banners: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        pagination: true,
        pagNums: false
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/* Getting the new tags to behave */
article, aside, audio, canvas, command, datalist, details, embed, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, keygen, meter, nav, output, progress, section, source, video {
    display:block;
}
mark, rp, rt, ruby, summary, time {
    display:inline;
}
/*********************************Global Properties**********************************/
html {
    width:100%;
}
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    color:#000;
    min-width:984px;
    background:#f8f8f8
}
.ic {
    border:0;
    float:right;
    background:#fff;
    color:#f00;
    width:50%;
    line-height:10px;
    font-size:10px;
    margin:-220% 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0
}
#page3 {
    min-width:1034px;
}
.main {
    width:984px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:25px;
}
a {
    color:#f00058;
    outline:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.col-1, .col-2 {
    float:left;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.extra-wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
}
p {
    margin-bottom:18px;
}
.p1 {
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
.p2 {
    margin-bottom:15px !important;
}
.p3 {
    margin-bottom:30px !important;
}
.p4 {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
.p5 {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.reg {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.fleft {
    float:left;
}
.fright {
    float:right;
}
.alignright {
    text-align:right;
}
.aligncenter {
    text-align:center;
}
.it {
    font-style:italic;
}
.color-1 {
    color:#f00058;
}
.color-2 {
    color:#7c7c7c;
}
.img-border1 {
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.img-border2 {
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
/*********************************Boxes**********************************/
.indent {
    padding:0 15px;
}
.indent-top {
    padding-top:5px;
}
.indent-left {
    padding-left:30px;
}
.indent-right {
    padding-right:35px;
}
.indent-bot {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.indent-bot2 {
    margin-bottom:18px;
}
.indent-bot3 {
    margin-bottom:45px;
}
.prev-indent-bot {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.img-indent-bot {
    margin-bottom:25px !important;
}
.margin-bot {
    margin-bottom:35px;
}
.img-indent {
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 0px 0;
}
.img-indent2 {
    float:left;
    margin:0 30px 0px 0;
}
.img-indent3 {
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 0px 0;
}
.img-indent-r {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0px 0px 20px;
}
.buttons a:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.menu li a, .list-1 li a, .list-2 li a, .link, .button, h1 a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
/*********************************header*************************************/
header {
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
h1 {
    padding:36px 0 0 22px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:27px;
}
h1 a {
    display:block;
    width:230px;
    height:77px;
    text-indent:-9999em;
    background:url(../images/wedding-logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
h1 em {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:2em;
    color:#888;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top:31px;
}
/*********************************Menu**********************************/
.menu-row {
    width:100%;
    padding:1px 0 5px;
    background:url(../images/menu-row-tail.png) center top repeat-x;
}
#page1 .menu-row {
    margin-bottom:22px;
}
.menu {
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/menu-spacer.gif) left top no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/menu-spacer.gif) right top no-repeat;
}
.menu li a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:59px;
    padding:0 50px;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.menu li a.active, .menu > li > a:hover {
    background:url(../images/menu-active-tail.gif) 0 0 repeat-x #f00058;
}


/*********************************Drop Down**********************************/
ul#nav {
    margin: 0 0 0 200px; 
}

ul.drop a {
    display:block; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
    background: #555; color: #fff; 
}

ul.drop {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 107; 
    float: left; 
}

ul.drop li {
    float: left; 
    line-height: 1.3em; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    zoom: 1; 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
}

ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 109; 
    cursor: default; 
    background: #1e7c9a; 
}

ul.drop ul { 
    /*visibility: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%; 
    left: 0; */
display:none;
    z-index: 108; 
    width: 195px; 
    background: #555; 
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
}

ul.drop ul li { 
    float: none; 
}

ul.drop ul ul { 
    top: -2px; 
    left: 100%; 
}

ul.drop li:hover > ul { 
    /*visibility: visible */
    display: block;
}


/*********************************Slider**********************************/
.slider-wrapper {
    width:745px;
    height:540px;
    padding:54px 0 0 150px;
    background:url(../images/slider-bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slider {
    width:690px;
    height:460px;
}
.items {
    display:none;
}
.pagination {
    position:absolute;
    left:290px;
    bottom:-62px;
    z-index:99
}
.pagination li {
    float:left;
    padding-right:6px;
}
.pagination a {
    display:block;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background:url(../images/slider-pagination.png) right top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.pagination li.current a {
    cursor:default;
}
.pagination li.current a,  .pagination a:hover {
    background-position:left top;
}
/*********************************Content*************************************/
#content {
    width:100%;
    padding:35px 0 53px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:37px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#000;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:2em;
    color:#000;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
h6 {
    color:#f00058;
}
.tdate-1 {
    display:block;
    color:#7c7c7c;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:20px;
}
.tdate-1 a {
    color:#7c7c7c;
}
.border-bot {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background:url(../images/pic-4.gif) 0 bottom repeat-x;
}
.q1, .q2, .q3 {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.quote-marker1 {
    display:block;
    width:15px;
    height:21px;
    background:url(../images/pic-1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:-1px;
    z-index:2;
}
.quote-marker2 {
    display:block;
    width:15px;
    height:21px;
    background:url(../images/pic-2.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.q1 .quote-bot {
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    background:url(../images/quote-bot.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.q2 .quote-bot {
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
    background:url(../images/quote-bot.jpg) left bottom no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.quote-top {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:5px;
    background:url(../images/quote-top.jpg) right top no-repeat;
}
.quote {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#7c7c7c;
    background:url(../images/quote-tail.jpg) right top repeat-y;
}
.quote .padding {
    padding:18px 25px 19px 30px;
}
.q3 {
    background:url(../images/pic-3.png) 0 3px no-repeat;
    color:#7c7c7c;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-bottom:17px;
}
.q3 .padding {
    padding:0 0 0 35px;
}
/* -- gallery  begin --*/
#gallery {
    width:1034px;
    height:870px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#js {
    position:relative;
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:25px;
}
div.content {
    /* The display of content is enabled using jQuery so that the slideshow content won't display unless javascript is enabled. */
    display: none;
    width: 410px;
    height: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.content img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
div.content a, div.navigation a {
}
div.content a:focus, div.content a:hover, div.content a:active {
}
div.controls {
    position:relative;
}
div.controls a {
    padding: 0px;
}
div.ss-controls {
    float: left;
    display:none;
}
div.nav-controls {
    width:100%;
    height:27px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:56px;
}
div.nav-controls a.prev {
    display:block;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url(../images/gallery-prev.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999em;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-47px;
    z-index:99;
}
div.nav-controls a.next {
    display:block;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url(../images/gallery-next.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999em;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-47px;
    z-index:99;
}
div.slideshow-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
    z-index:1;
    width:900px;
    margin-right:48px;
    float:left;
}
div.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
}
div.slideshow {
}
div.caption {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div.slideshow span.image-wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.slideshow a.advance-link {
    display: block;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
div.slideshow a.advance-link:hover, div.slideshow a.advance-link:active, div.slideshow a.advance-link:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.download {
    float: right;
}
div.caption-container {
    float:right;
    width: 270px;
    height: 620px;
    position:relative;
}
span.image-caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    z-index:10;
    background:#fff;
}
div#thumbs {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
ul.thumbs {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
ul.thumbs li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    width:140px;
}
ul.thumbs li.last {
    margin:0;
}
ul.thumbs li span {
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#f9f9f9;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
}
a.thumb {
    display:block;
    width:132px;
    height:132px;
    padding:3px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5
}
a.thumb:focus {
    outline: none;
}
#controls {
    width:100%;
}
div.pagination {
    clear: both;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
div.top.pagination {
    display:none;
}
div.navigation div.bottom {
    display:none;
}
div.pagination a, div.pagination span.current, div.pagination span.ellipsis {
    padding:0 4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
}
div.pagination a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffeaa8;
}
div.pagination span.current {
    color:#ffeaa8;
}
div.pagination span.ellipsis {
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 0 3px 2px;
}
/* -- gallery end --*/


.list-1 li {
    line-height:20px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 15px;
    background:url(../images/marker-1.gif) 0 12px no-repeat;
}
.list-1 li a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#7c7c7c;
}
.list-1 li a:hover {
    color:#f00058;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.link:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.link-1 {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:27px;
    padding-left:39px;
    background:url(../images/marker-2.gif) 0 0px no-repeat;
}
.link-1:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.text-1 {
    display:block;
    color:#f00058;
}
.text-2 {
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    font-style:normal !important;
}
dl span {
    float:left;
    width:98px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/*********************************Contact Form**********************************/
#contact-form {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
#contact-form label {
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#contact-form input {
    float:left;
    width:490px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1.25em;
    color:#000;
    padding:7px 9px 6px;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background:#fff;
    outline:none;
}
#contact-form textarea {
    float:left;
    height:339px;
    width:490px;
    max-height:339px;
    max-width:490px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1.25em;
    color:#000;
    padding:7px 9px;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:auto;
    outline:none;
}
.text-form {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:75px;
    color:#000;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.buttons {
    padding:13px 10px 0 0;
    text-align:right;
}
.buttons a {
    margin-left:25px;
}
/*********************************Footer**********************************/
footer {
    width:100%;
    padding:10px 0 10px;
    background:url(../images/footer-tail.gif) center top repeat-x;
}
.list-services {
    padding:7px 6px 0 0px;
    float:right;
}
.list-services li {
    float:left;
    padding:0 9px 0 0;
}
.list-services a {
    display:block;
    width:41px;
    height:46px;
    text-indent:-9999em;
    background:url(../images/social-icons.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.list-services .item-2 {
    background-position:-50px 0;
}
.list-services .item-3 {
    background-position:-100px 0;
}
.footer-text {
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 0 0px;
}
.footer-text span {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not too broad, it's too specific :-) You should try making it a bit shorter and more generic. Maybe remove unneeded fluff?

Answer (score 0):

try this CSS

```
<style>
  #select-choice-2-button {float:right;}
  .ui-header .ui-title {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} 
</style>
```

try this html

```
<select name="forma" id="select-choice-2"  data-native-menu="false" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="">More</option>
<option value="http://">Help</option>
<option value="http://">Info</option>
```